# Replacing items in an array using two regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

Can you use two regex in preg_replace to match and replace items in an array?
So for example:

Assume you have:

```
Array 
(
    [0] => mailto:9bc0d67a-0@acoregroup.com
    [1] => mailto:347c6b@acoregroup.com
    [2] => mailto:3b3cce0a-0@acoregroup.com
    [3] => mailto:9b690cc@acoregroup.com
    [4] => mailto:3b7f59c1-4bc@acoregroup.com
    [5] => mailto:cc62c936-7d@acoregroup.com
    [6] => mailto:5270f9@acoregroup.com
}
```

and you have two variables holding regex strings:

```
$reg = '/mailto:[\w-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+/i';
$replace = '/[\w-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+/i';
```

can I:

```
preg_replace($reg,$replace,$matches);
```

In order to replace "mailto:9bc0d67a-0@acoregroup.com" with "9bc0d67a-0@acoregroup.com" in each index of the array.

Comment: The $1 in the answer(s) below will expand into the 1st () sub-expression.  Notice that we added ( and ) around the part of the match you are interested in.

Comment: The third parameter to preg_match() can be an array.  In that case, preg_match() will return an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$newArray = preg_replace('/mailto:([\w-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+)/i', '$1', $oldArray);
```

<sup>Haven't tested</sup>

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $ind => $value)
  $array[$ind] = preg_replace('/mailto:([\w-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+)/i', '$1', $value);
```

EDIT: gahooa's solution is probably better, because it moves the loop inside preg_replace.

Comment: The first matching group.  In this case whatever "([\w-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+)" matches.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for the '$1' submatch groups, as others have already pointed out. But why can't you just do the following:

```
// strip 'mailto:' from the start of each array entry
$newArray = preg_replace('/^mailto:\s*/i', '', $array);
```

In fact, seeing as your regex doesn't allow the use of ':' anywhere in the email addresses, you could do it with a simple `str_replace()`:

```
// remove 'mailto:' from each item
$newArray = str_replace('mailto:', '', $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

For this type of substitution you should use str_replace it is mutch faster [and strongly suggested by the online documentation](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
   $array = str_replace('mailto:', '', $array);
```

Comment: Definitely agree on the use of `str_replace` in this situation. It's more than twice as fast than gahooa's regex. For the record, I also tried a loop with a `substr($str, 7)` construction. It's faster than the regex, but does not beat `str_replace`.